# How to restart count based on a criteria, but continue count if the same criteria is found below in Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I got the following scenario and my attempt gives a wrong result.

Would appreciate a helping hand here:

[image]

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing) a file with the data for test, should you feel like jumping in...

Comment: Check this - https://support.google.com/docs/thread/145076388/how-to-add-row-number-over-partition-by-two-columns-on-google-sheets?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, @Pankaj, but this one starts over the count when the criteria is found again down below and it takes date as criteria...I'm still trying to find the right tweak here, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more straightforward approach. Delete everything (including the header) from Col B, then place the following in B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Task Nº"; IF(A2:A="",,COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)))})`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Pankaj's direction and with a tweak, here is the solution:

```
={"Task Nº";ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), SORT(ROW(A2:A),SORT(ROW(A2:A),A2:A,1),1)-MATCH(A2:A,SORT(A2:A),0),))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula below in cell B2 and then AUTO FILL.

```
=countif($A$2:A2,A2)
```

Comment: WOW! So obvious, once it's there. Thanks!